# What is the output vector shape in pair distance (pdist)?

Tags: python-3.x

```
from numpy.spatial.distance import pdist

X = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1]]

Y = pdist(X)
print(Y)
#   1.0000    1.0000    2.2361    1.4142    2.8284    1.4142
```

I have an array `X` of shape (4,2) which I pass to pdist. I don't understand why the shape of the output `Y` is (6,).

Comment: Hi there, could you use the code formatting block? Use ``` around code to make it clearer.

Comment: Duplicate of [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pdist` outputs all unique internal distances in your matrix `X`.
In your simple case, it outputs the distance between the following index pairs:

```
[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3]
```

The equation for the expected number of outputs is `N(N-1)/2` for an input array of shape (N,M).

Comment: How can know index pairs from the above case?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you imagine a 4x4 distance matrix (so `matrix[0,1]` is the distance between point `0` and `1`), `pdist` returns all element of the upper triangle, not including the diagonal. The index pairs I listed in my answer maps directly to the distances output by `pdist` in your question.